# Fatal error when I go 'Manage categories' on admin

Tags: category, admin, fatal-error

I'm getting a fatal error when I go 'Manage categories' on admin

It seems other menu working fine like manage products but manage categories is not work

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php' (include_path='/home/mywebsite/www/includes/src:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mywebsite/www/includes/src/Magedev_Productposition_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs.php on line 8

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: it seems like you are using some third party extension which is causing the error.. try disabling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System -> Tools -> Compilation`, `Re-run compilation`, `check mange category`, if still issue exists, try `Disable Compilation`, and check again

Comment: It works! Thank you! Can I know reason? I disable 'Magedev_Productposition' but still got error. After I disable Compilation, it works.. Do I have to always disable Compilation? Any disadvantage for disable compilation?

Comment: What Compilation does is, collects all modules and codes and places it into include/src to minimize the compilation time from back-end, but from Magento 1.4, this doesn't speed-up your website anymore, if you make any change in modules, you need to compile it every time, so, it's better to Disable Compilation

Comment: Very useful information. On internet and a magento book, I have read I have to enable compliation to speed up. If it's not ture, there is no reason to enable to this Thank yo uagain!